# Why is the nose cone of the Su-34 white?

Tags: paint, nose, russia, radome, sukhoi-su-34

The title says it all. It can be clearly seen, for example, in this image:

[image: SU-34]
(image source: [Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:ROYAL_AIR_FORCE_TYPHOONS_INTERCEPT_10_RUSSIAN_AIRCRAFT_IN_ONE_MISSION_MOD_45158990.jpg))

The rest of the jet seems to have a camouflage.

Comment: Tips of the vertical stabs are also white...

Comment: [Related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/89180/15311)

Comment: @Rodrigo, Now we should probably mark _this_ question a dup of that newer one, because it has a good answer, and the answers are the same for both, and the accepted answer for this Q is incorrect.

Comment: @Zeus I would wait a few weeks before making this a duplicate.

Comment: @RonBeyer: Stabs tips are white because they are also radomes hosting VHF antennas ([3D blueprint](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/14/4c/2b/144c2b53877d070437168814d35d6e32.jpg)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is all part of the camouflage.

The blue parts on the bottom make the aircraft hard to identify from below against a blue-background (sky). The dark parts on the top make it difficult to identify from above against a dark background (ground).

The white parts make the aircraft's size/shape difficult to determine. This helps to confuse the enemy by making the aircraft seem farther away than it really is.

Comment: totally agreed, in addition to Ron's answer each country has its own camouflage color reference/catalouge lets say. I have found it hard to get the Russian one but you can have a look at the US one here       
  https://www.milspeccoating.com/Federal-Standard-595-Colors-s/41.htm#products-595

Comment: I would think more of a "fade" from grey to white, than a sharp line, would be much better, even if the fade is only over say 6 to 12 inches or so.

Comment: https://www.ausairpower.net/Su-34-Fullback/NAPO-Su-34-Fullback-V.Kuzmin-0112-3.jpg I have seen photos of SU-34s with grey radomes and matching vert stab tips. I am not convinced that a bright white radome is considered a form of camouflage. I would like to see some sort of reference to back it up.

Comment: I'm with Mike Sowsun.  In fact, highlighting the nose and tail like this would provide a clear reference point that could actually aid one in estimating range.  Maybe this is a training or aggressor version?

Comment: I am starting to think the radomes are actually “radio transparent” grey or white as per this modelling website: https://internethobbies.com/products/hataka-hobby-ultimate-su34-fleet-fullback-russian-air-force-paint-set-6-colors-17ml-bottles

Comment: Radomes are not 100% transparent to microwaves.  Their loss and other effects of the antennas radiation pattern are minimized in the design, construction, and materials used.  But they are not 100% transparent.

Comment: Note that the cover of the rear-facing radar is NOT white..

Comment: @SteveSh: Well matching radomes materials have a dielectric attenuation less than 0.2 dB, about -3%. But radomes also include protections against lightning (diverter strips) which may deform the antenna radiation pattern (increasing energy in side lobes)

Comment: Agreed.  But in some places engineers would sell their first born for a couple of tenths of dB more sensitivity <wink>.

Comment: @SteveSh: That's likely why the radomes are white, to get the lowest noise temperature possible.

Comment: I'm exhausting my knowledge of radomes here, so do not know how the temperature of the radome affects the noise temperature/noise figure of the radar front end.  The temperature of the radiator element or the front end LNA, maybe yes.  But not the temperature of the the radome.

Comment: @SteveSh: When the radome receives energy from the outside (including by friction), it radiates a part of this energy in the inner volume, and some reaches the antenna, this may be expressed as a [noise temperature](https://www.ece.mcmaster.ca/faculty/nikolova/antenna_dload/current_lectures/L07_Noise.pdf), remember the cosmic background radiation is [noise temperature of about 3K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discovery_of_cosmic_microwave_background_radiation). (You can include '@mins' in your message, for notification)

Answer (score 1):

They're white because that's the cove of the radar dome(Radome) by being white, they reflect em interference and thermal suns rays to keep radar clutter to a minimum

Comment: I assume the same. Like the black noses of older passenger planes.

Comment: The color has nothing to do with whether or not it reflects EM (electro magnetic) interference [signals].  White does reflect solar radiation, which can help reduce sun loading (heating) on the antenna and other electronics behind the radome.

Comment: How about the vertical stabs then? Also, the cover of the rear-facing radar is NOT white..

Comment: Because they protect sensitive instruments while allowing electronic signals to pass through, nose cones – also known as radomes – must be made from specific materials. These materials often include fiberglass, quartz, honeycomb and foam cores; as well as various chemical resins

Comment: @juzzlin - Because there's probably an antenna of some sort on top of the stabilizers.

Comment: This answer is the good one. @juzzlin: White radomes at stabs tips are for [VHF antennas](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/14/4c/2b/144c2b53877d070437168814d35d6e32.jpg).

Comment: @mins: It may be right, but if we're being fair, neither cite their references.

Comment: You might want to look at this SE post, https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/25368/how-are-antennas-integrated-into-stealth-aircraft.  Everyplace there's an antenna, there's a radome of some sort or other over it.