# What are these two circular areas on the fuslage of Fokker 100?

Tags: aircraft-design, feature-identification

There are two circular areas on the fuslage of Fokker 100 which are shown in the bellow image. What are those? Why are the above these two areas written "do not paint"?

[image]

Comment: After googling "static port plates", found these two also https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/56625/what-are-the-static-ports-in-a-boeing-767 and https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/17440/how-does-a-pitot-plate-work hope help